# prototype method are unresolved

Tags: javascript, phpstorm

i'm trying to write some class in Javascript in PHPStorm and when i call method from another method i get unresolved method what am i doing wrong?

the code is

```
(function(){
    var A = function(){};
    A.prototype.method_A = function(){};
    A.prototype.method_B = function(){
        this.method_A();
    }
})();
```

but if i do the following code it resolves the inner methods but not the outer methods

```
(function () {
    var E = function () {
    };
    E.prototype = {
        method_A: function () {
            this.method_B()
        },
        method_B: function () {

        }
    };
    E.prototype.method_C = function () {
        this.method_A() // Unresolved function or method
    }
})();
```

in browser it works like a charm but in the phpstorm editor it's saying unresolved method so i want to understand if i'm making something wrong

Comment: The code you posted results in no net effect to the global environment. The first and second samples declare local variables inside an anonymous function, so after that code it'll be as if nothing at all has happened.

Comment: i'm in the beginning of my script and it's annoying me, it will affect the global in further do...

Comment: If I copy and paste your code, it works fine.  Are you sure you're instantiating an instance of `A`?